# Apollo integration tests: How to set context?

Tags: graphql, apollo

In my normal apollo server, context is set

```
return new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: (expressCtx) => {
    ...
  },
});
```

But when testing using [`apollo-server-testing`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/), how do I set it on each request to something potentially different? I initialized the server in a `beforeAll` test hook. Or is the only way to initialize a different `ApolloServer` instance with the desired context?